# Consistent colors among bar plots

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, data-visualization, bar-chart

I have a dataset where each column is a country, each row is a year and I want to show, in order to later build a bar chart race, the top 5 countries per year and how they change position over time.

In order to do this, I want for each country to have the same bar color for every year, even if they change position between years. That's why I rank the data and use their ranking for the y-position, instead of sorting it.

When I run the following code,  the countries color from the first 3 bar plots (1996 to 1998) is consistent even if one them shifts position, but from 1999 to 2001, every country changes colors, remaining consistent until 2001.

```
# Plotting several time periods, with ranking
dates = [1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001]

# How many elements to show in each graph...
topN = 5

# Plot grid
fig, ax_array = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 6, figsize = (10, 2.5), dpi = 144, tight_layout = True)

for ax, date in zip(ax_array, dates):

    # Series with desired date
    s = exp_data_wide.loc[date]
    # Rank every country, then drop NaN values
    s_rank = s.rank(method = 'first').dropna()

    # X and Y values for the graphic
    # Since I've got a large list of countries, and I must avoid sorting the data, I work with the last N values of the rank
    y = s_rank[s_rank >= len(s_rank) - topN]
    x = s[y.index]

    ax.barh (y = y, width = x.values, color = colors, tick_label = x.index)
    ax.set_title(date, fontsize = 'smaller')
    prettify(ax)
```

[image: Bar chart output screenshot]

For example, I don't know why France bar get plotted in pink the first three years, then it changes to green in 1999 and remains that way the following years.

What I need is plot each country with the same bar color for every year.

Can you help me figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

#### Correcting Y values in bar plot for ranked series

The problem here is how the x and y variables are defined and plotted.

```
y = s_rank[s_rank >= len(s_rank) - topN]

c1    3.0
c2    6.0
c3    2.0
c4    5.0
c5    4.0
c6    1.0
Name: 1996, dtype: float64

x = s[y.index]
c1    3168
c2    6369
c3    2408
c4    5441
c5    5430
c6    1440
Name: 1996, dtype: int64
```

In this example, the order of rect drawing will be c1, c2,...,c6. So the colors are applied in that order as well. What you want is to draw in the order of your ranking. Solve this by simply sorting your y values.

```
y = s_rank[s_rank >= len(s_rank) - topN].sort_values()
```

Here is an example where I set rects[0].set_color('r') to demonstrate what is happening with the order of the plotting.

[image]

Here is an example of implementation of this solution.

[image]

```
#generate data
rng = np.random.default_rng(12345)
idx = ['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6']
rng = np.random.default_rng()
exp_data_wide = pd.DataFrame({
    1996: rng.integers(low=500, high=10000, size=6),
    1997: rng.integers(low=500, high=10000, size=6),
    1998: rng.integers(low=500, high=10000, size=6),
    1999: rng.integers(low=500, high=10000, size=6),
    2000: rng.integers(low=500, high=10000, size=6),
    2001: rng.integers(low=500, high=10000, size=6),
}, index=idx)

#set dates, topN, colors
dates = [1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001]
topN = 5
colors = ['#aaf542','#5c0794','#ae63e0','#a6a2a8','#97b814','#b86314']

fig, ax_array = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 6, figsize = (10, 2.5), dpi = 144, tight_layout = True)
for ax, date in zip(ax_array, dates):
    #Apply rank
    s = exp_data_wide[date]
    s_rank = s.rank(method = 'first').dropna()
    #define x/y
    y = s_rank[s_rank >= len(s_rank) - topN].sort_values()
    x = s[y.index]
    #plot
    rects = ax.barh (y = y, width = x.values, color=colors, tick_label = x.index)
    ax.set_title(date, fontsize = 'smaller')
    rects[0].set_color('r')
    #style
    [ax.spines[s].set_visible(False) for s in ['top','right','bottom','left']]
    ax.grid(axis='x', dashes=(8,3), alpha=0.3)
    ax.tick_params(axis='both', left=False, bottom=False)
    ax.set_xlim(0,10000)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering this question! Unfortunately, this doesn't solve my problem: What I'm trying to achieve is to make the country bar color constant among each year, even if it changes position.

In the terms of your example, 'c4' should always have a 'brown' color bar for every year, 'c1' a 'red' one, 'c3' a 'purple' one and so on...

Will keep trying to figure this out. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Try using a dictionary and accessing with keys of  the y axis in each for loop.